# Parse string of words into set of words

Tags: c++, parsing, set, stringstream

Here is the function I am writing to parse a string of words into a set of words.

```
std::set<std::string> parseStringToWords(string rawWord) 
{
    getline(cin,rawWord);
    std::set<std::string> myset;
    istringstream iss(rawWord);
    string word;
    while(iss >> word) {
        myset.insert(word);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure what I have is right so far, but I'm not sure what to do in the while loop. Any hints?

Comment: Pass each word to an output iterator. Maybe define a convenience wrapper that uses that to return a vector of words.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really new to c++. Is there a simpler way or can you explain your way?

Comment: Since you need to return a set, you should declare one.  Then insert values into it in your loop and return it when the loop ends.

Comment: Am I on the right track now?

Comment: Not that it matters, but the passing of `rawWord` as a parameter emits an odd odor. Was there a point to requiring it passed as a parameter only to be ignored in favor of the (unchecked) `getline` result?

Comment: What I'm supposed to do is "Complete the code to convert a string containing a rawWord to a set of words."

Comment: Not knowing the criteria is somewhat limiting, but if all you need to is split a string of words to a `std::set<std::string>`, some stream iterators and the iterator-based `std::set` constructor make it pretty simple, [see here](http://ideone.com/vEX1o7).

Comment: I don't think I can use the auto keyword. Can you post an alternate version without using auto?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code to hopefully lead you in good directions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>               // std::string
#include <set>                  // std::set
#include <sstream>              // std::istringstream

namespace my {
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::istringstream;
    using std::set;
    using std::string;

    auto set_of_words( const string& s )
        -> set<string>
    {
        set<string> result;
        istringstream iss( s );
        string word;
        while( iss >> word )
        {
            result.insert( word );
        }
        return result;
    }

    auto getline( const string& prompt )
        -> string
    {
        string result;
        cout << prompt;
        getline( cin, result );
        return result;
    }
}  // namespace my

auto main() -> int
{
    using namespace my;
    using namespace std;

    const set<string> words = set_of_words( getline( "A line of words, please: ") );
    cout << "You entered these unique_words:" << endl;
    for( const string word : words )
    {
        cout << "* " << word << endl;
    }
}
```

The main problem with this code is that it doesn't check for or handle failures. In professional work much of the code is often concerned with failure checking and handling. In particular the `my::getline` function should not just silently return a result when input fails.

Another problem is lack of reusability, due to lack of abstraction. As I already mentioned in a comment to the question, a natural way for a seasoned programmer is to let the split-into-words function pass the words to an output iterator. This then facilitates both direct use for various purposes such as outputting the words one at a line, or adding them to a set, or putting them at the end of a vector, …; and it facilitates the coding of convenience wrappers for such purposes. More importantly it's a general principle of just not needlessly constraining oneself to a given data representation. But on the other hand, not wasting work on hopeful generalization, because in the end one might discover that it's not used.